# Does chlorophyll have any health benefits for humans?

Tags: alternative-medicine

I was surprised to see in advertisements for "miracle" natural / alternative / herbal etc. medicine that they contain "liquid chlorophyll" and that is really useful for our health.

I wondered how it can be, because chlorophyll is actually what plants use for photosynthesis, so humans could make absolutely no use of it. Even if our whole skin could photosynthesize, it would provide only a small fraction of the required energy. By the way, absolutely any plant we eat contains chlorophyll, so why would anyone not eating exclusively meat require additional chlorophyll, even if it was useful?

The Wikipedia article shows absolutely nothing about any medical uses of [chlorophyll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll). A Google search for chlorophyll  and "medical uses", "health benefits", etc. returned only sites belonging to companies actively selling it, and describing it as a miraculous cure-all. I did not manage to find any independent or independent-seeming article about the subject.

Comment: We have a [similar question about wheatgrass](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5842/5), where chlorophyll is also mentioned in the claim.

Comment: actually only greens contain chlorophyll, it's what makes them green

Comment: As far as I can tell, chlorophyll is a major source of dietary magnesium.  Still looking for a definitive source, though.

Answer (score -1):

[Chlorophyll Revisited: Anti-inflammatory Activities of Chlorophyll
a and Inhibition of Expression of TNF-α Gene by the Same](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22038065) looked at a topical application of [decoction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoction) of leaves onto injured rats' paws, and found:

> chlorophyll a, and not chlorophyll b, when applied topically, showed
>   promising anti-inflammatory activity